# groovy xml parsing function

Tags: java, groovy

I wish to have a groovy function which can take 2 or more parameters something like `input`, `find_tag`.

I wrote something like below to test(not function), but it does not give me `D_1164898448`. Please help me with it.

```
def temp="""<Portals objVersion=\"1.1.19\">
<vector xsi:type=\"domainservice:Portals\"  objVersion=\"1.1.19\">
<domainName>D_1164898448</domainName>
<address xsi:type=\"metadata:NodeRef\"  objVersion=\"1.1.19\">
<host>Komodo</host>
<port>18442</port>
</address>
</vector>
</Portals>"""

def   fInput="domainName"

def records = new XmlParser().parseText(temp)
def t=records.findAll{ it.fInput}.text()
println t
```

**Update**

for attribute i am doin something like below

```
println "id = ${records.attribute("id")}"
```

but like wise how to do it for nodes?

```
println "host = ${records.vector.address.host.text()}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the exact path to the XML tag you're searching for, you can do something like this to get the content of all tags with the given name:

```
def t = records."**"."$fInput".text()
```

To access attributes from a given XML node you can also use the `@` notation, e.g.

```
records.vector.@objVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

- turn off namespace awareness, so that XmlParser won't throw an error on encountering unbound `xsi:` prefix. You can do it by passing right arguments to `XmlParser` constructor.
- properly traverse the DOM tree returned by parser - it returns a `Node`, not a list, and using `findAll` the way you used will not work
- (optionally) remove backslashes from before double quotes in your XML, as escaping double quotes inside a heredoc is not necessary

Your code after corrections:

```
def temp="""
    <Portals objVersion="1.1.19">
        <vector xsi:type="domainservice:Portals"  objVersion="1.1.19">
            <domainName>D_1164898448</domainName>
            <address xsi:type="metadata:NodeRef"  objVersion="1.1.19">
                <host>Komodo</host>
                <port>18442</port>
            </address>
        </vector>
   </Portals>
"""

def   fInput="domainName"

def records= new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(temp)
def t = records.vector."$fInput".text()
println t
```

Running it displays 'D_1164898448', as expected.

Comment: Is there something similar to `${records.attribute("id")}"` to get the node, where in place of `id` i can give my full DOM tree path to the node?

Comment: XmlReader returns a `groovy.util.Node`, which is not the same as DOM Node and so does not support XPath expressions. What it does support are GPath expressions, described here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/GPath . See if you can use this. If not, and you require full XPath support, you'll probably need to use an external library; see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+with+Groovy+and+XPath

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you must use XPath expression here, or if you input xml *excactly* as you show in question, i'm recommend to you regexp like

```
def temp = ".." //your temp

def m = temp =~ /<domainName>(.*)</domainName>/
print m[0][1] // should be your domain
```

more about groovy regexp http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

Comment: how can `(.*)` be parsed? coz when i use `println "<$fInput>(.*)</$fInput>"` it simply gives  me `<domainName>(.*)</domainName>`

Comment: sorry, i'm was think you familiar with Groovy Regexp. Edited with more explain.

Comment: @AlexeySviridov You're advising parsing XML with Regexp?  Really?

Comment: @tim_yates I'm point to simple thing. Not always nessessary to complexly parse xml, especially when xml contains three line, and you need a simple value between two tags (of course this not work for large and complex hierarhical structure). Reread my answer, i'm highlite word "exactly". In case of this question regexp much more efficient then full xml parse.